# Debugging Obfuscated Stack Traces pulled from Android Developer Console Error Reports

Tags: android, stack-trace, proguard

I've had an app on Google Play for a little while now which hasn't historically been obfuscated.  From time to time there will be an error on the user's device and I will get a report through the Android Developer Console Application Error Reports, which lets me see a stack trace of the crash which I can use to fix the bug.  I've just released a new version of my app which is obfuscated for the first time (ProGuard), and am curious whether I can use the ProGuard `retrace` tool to de-obfuscate the Stack Traces reported through the Android Developer Console specifically.

I have read the *Decoding Obfuscated Stack Traces* section [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), but I'm still not certain what the format is of the stack trace file (or standard input) that the `retrace` command accepts and whether this is the same format errors are reported in by the Android Developer Console Error Reports.  I've kept the all important `mapping.txt` file.  Basically all I want to know is, when the first new error stack trace rolls into the Android Developer Console, is it going to be presented in a format that I can run the `retrace` tool on, or, do I need to be collecting stack traces in some other specific format using some other tool if I want a hope of reconstructing the stack trace using `retrace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReTrace should work fine for these stack traces; they're like ordinary Java stack traces. If you ever get stack traces in a format that ReTrace doesn't recognize, you can still specify a custom regular expression with ReTrace's -regex option.